# Help with scanf behaving differently on Big Endian system

Tags: c, scanf

My code is supposed to read a line from the user, if the line starts with "*output*" then it prints out "*Line is output*" and waits for the user to enter another line.

If the line starts with "*input*" it prints out "*Line is input*" and terminates.

My code works fine on an Intel PC, however on a Debian SPARC it seems the scanf doesnt wait for input after the first time and just reads in an empty line or something infinitely.

Where am I going wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
char buf[9000];
char key[5];
char *p=buf;

int readMore=1;

while(readMore)
{
    //read in one line from stdin into buffer
    scanf("%[^\n]",buf);
    fflush(stdin);

    sscanf(p, "%s",key); //get key from buffer
    printf("Key:%s\n",key); //print key

    if (strcmp("output",key)==0)
    {
        printf("Line is output\n");

    }
    if (strcmp("input",key)==0)
    {
        readMore=0;
        printf("Line is input\n");

        fflush(stdin);
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }
    key[0]=0;
    buf[0]=0;
}  //end while

return 0;
}
```

Fixed like this:

```
......
int bytes_read;
int nbytes = 100;

while(readMore)
{

      /* These 2 lines are the heart of the program. */
      p = (char *) malloc (nbytes + 1);
      bytes_read = getline (&p, &nbytes, stdin);
....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not an endian issue. This is about how buffering of standard input is performed on the different platforms. Basically, you can't use fflush() on standard input (or any other input stream) - the C Standard says that doing so is undefined.

Comment: @roman I'm really not all that clear why you think you need to flush the stream. Just remove the calls to fflush

Comment: Removed the calls but didnt help, I think the newline stays in stdin no? I think I fixed it by using getline instead of scanf though, Thanx.

Comment: Remove calls to fflush, but you might have to add an additional getchar() after the first scanf() to clear the line feed character. As usual, the comp.lang.c.faq answers the question: [here](http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush2.html) and [here](http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush.html).

Comment: I took the liberty to remove the little/big endian tags, as the issue is not at all related to them.